# Parsing XML in Node js: Zapier

Tags: node.js, zapier

I'm building a zapier app and I'm trying to parse an XML response from fetch. Unable to do so, any help?

Comment: You can also try [Fast XML Parser](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser) to parse XML into JS object. It can be used directly in browser including library file or in node package after installing the package.

Comment: For those who come looking to create a _zap_ rather than a 'zapier app', be aware that **a)** node doesn't provide any native XML functionality, and **b)** JS code zaps _"cannot require [...] "npm modules". Only the standard node.js library and the fetch package are available in the Code app."_. If you need this in a zap, `xml2json-light` is small enough to inline.

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

I'm not sure what you're having trouble with specifically, but we've heard reports of people finding success parsing xml using the `xml2js` npm package.

Comment: Cannot find module 'xml2js' is the error I'm getting

Comment: oh sorry, you'll need to install it from npm. `npm install -S xml2js`. There's snippets on the project page: https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js

Answer (score 0):

I think OP is working with SOAP-based APIs which return XML. You can work with  [pixl-xml lib](https://github.com/jhuckaby/pixl-xml). Just do `npm install pixl-xml` in your app source dir and then use the lib in your CLI app. Hope this helps. The code is from CLI doc.

```
const xml = require('pixl-xml');

const App = {
  // ...
  afterResponse: [
    (response, z, bundle) => {
      response.xml = xml.parse(response.content);
      return response;
    }
  ]
  // ...
};
```